# Android unable to unhold call using pjsip

Tags: android, pjsip

Im having this issue

> Error while trying to unHold call: java.lang.Exception: Title:
>   pjsua_call_reinvite2(id, param.p_opt, param.p_msg_data) Code: 70013
>   Description: Invalid operation (PJ_EINVALIDOP) Location:
>   ../src/pjsua2/call.cpp:605

I checked the specific line, there's an if condition to check if pjsua_has_video is true, which should be false in my case. Because for this app, i don't have video format available, at first i thought this flag is undefined, so i recompiled pjsip with the specific flag in config file set on 0 , but this still happens.

```
        try {
            if (hold) {
                MainActivity.currentCall.setHold(param);
                localHold = true;
GtmUtils.pushCustomEvent("CallInterruption",this);
            } else {

                CallSetting opt = param.getOpt();
                opt.setAudioCount(1);
                opt.setVideoCount(0);
                opt.setFlag(pjsua_call_flag.PJSUA_CALL_UNHOLD.swigValue());
                MainActivity.currentCall.reinvite(param);
                localHold = false;

                Crashlytics.log("Call " + operation);
                Crashlytics.log("ReInvite param: " + param);
                Crashlytics.log("Destination nr: " + number);
                Crashlytics.log("Timezone: " + timeZone.getID());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Crashlytics.logException(new Exception("Error while trying to " + operation + " call: " + e.toString()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code its working perfect for me.

```
CallOpParam prm;

     public void holdCall() {
            prm = new CallOpParam(true);
            try {
                currentCall.setHold(prm);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void unHoldCall() {
            prm.getOpt().setFlag(1);
            try {
                currentCall.reinvite(prm);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Thanks, Happy coding....